# Error import Filters in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I ran into a problem when using the telegram.ext module in my Python project in PyCharm. I installed the latest version of python-telegram-bot and checked the spelling of the imports but still getting the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext' (D:\Program Game\Python\lib\site-packages\telegram \ext_init_.py).

I would like to know how can I fix this error and continue using the telegram.ext module in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your code is

`from telegram.ext import Filters`

which does indeed give the error message you have shown us.

[The python-telegram-bot docs say that the Filters class no longer exists as of version 20.0](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html), and to use the functionality directly from the filters module, so what you should do instead is

`from telegram.ext import filters` (lowercase f)

which imports correctly for me.