# Python code with ConversationHandler not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot with python and i have got this code in hand. Though my VS Code Studio shows Filters and ConversationHandler modules are not working or sth

```
import telegram
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackQueryHandler

# Define the available dates for the pretest
DATES = ["May 1", "May 15", "May 29"]

# Define the available speaking days
SPEAKING_DAYS = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]

# Define the available time slots
TIME_SLOTS = ["10:00am - 10:12am", "10:12am - 10:24am", "10:24am - 10:36am", "10:36am - 10:48am",
              "10:48am - 11:00am", "11:00am - 11:12am", "11:12am - 11:24am", "11:24am - 11:36am",
              "11:36am - 11:48am", "11:48am - 12:00pm", "2:00pm - 2:12pm", "2:12pm - 2:24pm"]

# Define the Neuron Pretest Center telegram group ID
NEURON_GROUP_ID = "NEURON_GROUP_ID"

# Define the bot token
TOKEN = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE"

# Define the conversation states
DATE, TEST_TYPE, NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, SPEAKING_DAY, TIME_SLOT = range(6)


def start(update, context):
    """Starts the conversation with the user."""
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_dates_keyboard())
    update.message.reply_text('Welcome to Neuron Pretest Center! Please select a date from the options below:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return DATE


def build_dates_keyboard():
    """Builds the inline keyboard with the available dates."""
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(date, callback_data=date)] for date in DATES]
    return keyboard


def select_date(update, context):
    """Saves the selected date and asks for the test type."""
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    context.user_data['date'] = query.data
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_test_type_keyboard())
    query.edit_message_text(text='Great! You selected {}. Now, please select the type of test you want to take:'.format(context.user_data['date']), reply_markup=keyboard)
    return TEST_TYPE


def build_test_type_keyboard():
    """Builds the inline keyboard with the available test types."""
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("IELTS Pretest", callback_data="IELTS Pretest"), 
                 InlineKeyboardButton("CEFR Pretest", callback_data="CEFR Pretest")]]
    return keyboard


def select_test_type(update, context):
    """Saves the selected test type and asks for the name."""
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    context.user_data['test_type'] = query.data
    query.edit_message_text(text='You selected {}. Please enter your full name:'.format(context.user_data['test_type']))
    return NAME


def save_name(update, context):
    """Saves the name and asks for the phone number."""
    context.user_data['name'] = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text('Please enter your phone number:')
    return PHONE_NUMBER


def save_phone_number(update, context):
    """Saves the phone number and asks for the speaking day."""
    context.user_data['phone_number'] = update
def select_speaking_day(update, context):
    """Saves the selected speaking day and asks for the time slot."""
    context.user_data['speaking_day'] = update.message.text
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_time_slots_keyboard())
    update.message.reply_text('Please select a time slot:', reply_markup=keyboard)
    return TIME_SLOT


def build_time_slots_keyboard():
    """Builds the inline keyboard with the available time slots."""
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(slot, callback_data=slot)] for slot in TIME_SLOTS]
    return keyboard


def select_time_slot(update, context):
    """Saves the selected time slot and sends the registration information to the Neuron Pretest Center telegram group."""
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    context.user_data['time_slot'] = query.data
    registration_info = get_registration_info(context.user_data)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=NEURON_GROUP_ID, text=registration_info)
    query.edit_message_text(text='Thanks for choosing Neuron Pretest Center. Your registration is complete. We hope to see you soon!')
    return ConversationHandler.END


def get_registration_info(user_data):
    """Returns the formatted registration information."""
    info = "New registration:\n"
    info += "Date: {}\n".format(user_data['date'])
    info += "Test Type: {}\n".format(user_data['test_type'])
    info += "Name: {}\n".format(user_data['name'])
    info += "Phone Number: {}\n".format(user_data['phone_number'])
    info += "Speaking Day: {}\n".format(user_data['speaking_day'])
    info += "Time Slot: {}\n".format(user_data['time_slot'])
    return info


def cancel(update, context):
    """Cancels the conversation and sends a message to the user."""
    update.message.reply_text('The conversation has been cancelled. Goodbye!')
    return ConversationHandler.END


def main():
    """Starts the bot."""
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            DATE: [CallbackQueryHandler(select_date)],
            TEST_TYPE: [CallbackQueryHandler(select_test_type)],
            NAME: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, save_name)],
            PHONE_NUMBER: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, save_phone_number)],
            SPEAKING_DAY: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, select_speaking_day)],
            TIME_SLOT: [CallbackQueryHandler(select_time_slot)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried uninstalling python-telegram-bot and reinstalled it. The issue persists

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error import Filters in python-telegram-bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75846777/error-import-filters-in-python-telegram-bot)